# JavaScript Form Detection

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to detect the when the 'yes' radio button is chosen with JavaScript. This is a small lightweight form and does not have jQuery or other library installed. My goal is for it to work in most major browsers and be written in just a few lines of code.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        if(document.forms[0].test.buy){alert("Clicked yes.);
   </script> 

</head>
<body>
    <form name="test">
        Buy Ice cream?
        <input type="radio" name="buy" value="yes" /> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="buy" value="no" /> No<br />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I just want to note that your name makes this question priceless :p That said, jQuery is extremely lightweight and can be included without needing to host it yourself using google: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery. jQuery works on all major browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your radio button needs to handle the onClick event -

```
<input type="radio" name="buy" value="male" onClick="myYesFunc()" />Yes
```

then you'll need a javascript function to handle the event

```
function myYesFunc()
{
  alert ("Yes Clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event handling in this case

```
    <input type="radio" onclick="Call your function"/>
```

and in function call check the value of radio button and perform task